# JSLint 'Unexpected '(space)' error when I'm calling a html class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call a html class and switch the value of it then I get thsi error'Unexpected '(space)'. $('.online').val(2501);

```
/*global $, document, alert */
$(document).ready(function () {
                  
    "use strict";
    alert("Loaded");
    $('#social').html("This is my text ");
    $('.online').val(2501);   
});
```

Comment: What happens if you comment (or otherwise temporarily remove) the line you *think* is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces here

```
/*global $, document, alert */
$(document).ready(function () {
                  // <<<<<<<<
    "use strict";
    alert("Loaded");
    $('#social').html("This is my text ");
    $('.online').val(2501);   // <<<<<
});
```

and get

```
/*global $, document, alert */
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    alert("Loaded");
    $('#social').html("This is my text ");
    $('.online').val(2501);
});
```

and use consistent quotes - single or double

```
/*global $, document, alert */
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    alert("Loaded");
    $("#social").html("This is my text ");
    $(".online").val(2501);
});
```